# extracting rows of excel file in R

Tags: r, excel, list

If I have a list like the following

| Letter | Identifier |
| --- | --- |
| B | 023 |
| C | 764 |
| D | 023 |

I want my R code to return a list that is the following

| Letter | Identifier |
| --- | --- |
| B | 023 |
| D | 023 |

This is my attempt. I am new to R and any advice would be helpful!

```
for (x in df$Identifier){
      newlist <- df[c("023")] }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to subset data in R, most of which do not require a `for()` loop.

For example:

```
theText <-"letter,identifier
B,023
C,0764
D,023"

df <- read.csv(text=theText,colClasses = "character")

df[df$identifier == "023",]
```

...uses the `[` form of the extract operator to subset rows based on the value of `identifier`.

```
> df[df$identifier == "023",]
  letter identifier
1      B        023
3      D        023
```

Note that the placement of the `,` within the extract operator is important, as it tells R to extract based on row values instead of column values.

`base::subset()` is another alternative:

```
subset(df,identifier == "023")
```

returns

```
> subset(df,identifier == "023")
  letter identifier
1      B        023
3      D        023
```

A tidyverse solution uses `dplyr::filter()` as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   filter(identifier == '023')
```

...and the result:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% 
+      filter(identifier == '023')
  letter identifier
1      B        023
2      D        023
```

The presence of a `for()` loop in the original post begs the question of how does one create multiple data frames based on the value of a column in a data frame.

This can be accomplished with `split()`.

For example, the `mtcars` data frame has cars with 4, 6, or 8 cylinders. We can split the 32 rows of data into three separate data frames, grouped by cylinder count as follows:

```
dfList <- split(mtcars,mtcars$cyl)
names(dfList)
```

...and the output:

```
> names(dfList)
[1] "4" "6" "8"
```

we can count the number of rows in each data frame like this:

```
sapply(dfList,nrow)
```

...and the output:

```
> sapply(dfList,nrow)
 4  6  8 
11  7 14
```

Comment: Thank you! My true data set is much larger with 125,xxx rows and I keep getting the following error:   Error in `df[df$Product == "HO3"]`:
! Can't subset columns with `df$Product == "HO3"`.
✖ Logical subscript `df$Product == "HO3"` must be size 1 or 14, not 125242.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Error in exists(cacheKey, where = .rs.WorkingDataEnv, inherits = FALSE) : 
  invalid first argument                                                      
 Do you have any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: The error message tells you that you are trying to subset on columns, not rows. Your code is missing a comma. it should be `df[df$Product == "H03", ]` in order to subset on rows not columns. If my answer solves your problem, please accept and upvote it.